# Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1m PHP/8.1.4 Server at localhost Port 80

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I am not able to open the localhost/wordpress or localhost:80/wordpress. As soon as i search, it shows
"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1m PHP/8.1.4 Server at localhost Port 80". I redownloaded the wordpress file and placed it in the htdocs but nothing happened. I also tried installing JDK and JRE files but nothing happened. The TOMCAT server is also not working in XAMPP, It shows
"Problem detected: Tomcat Not Found!
Disabling Tomcat buttons
Run this program from your XAMPP root directory!". I am stuck at this point and don't know what to do next.

I am trying to open the localhost/wordpress to practice the website development on wordpress and I've never done it before.

Comment: Describe the steps you took to install the software, as this is likely to be the actual problem.

Comment: JDK, JRE, and Tomcat are all Java technologies; Wordpress is built in PHP; the two have no relationship at all. That means that a lot of the detail here isn't relevant, so all we've really got to go on is 1) you've installed XAMPP; 2) you've downloaded Wordpress. We don't really know what you're doing, and what instructions you're trying to follow, so could only make wild guesses at what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Despite my earlier comment that you haven't provided enough information, I'm going to take one wild guess: you say you "downloaded the wordpress file and placed it in the htdocs". Wordpress doesn't consist of one file, it consists of a whole *directory* of different files.

So my wild guess is that you've downloaded a zip file, which is a way of putting a whole bunch of files in one, and missed the word "unzip" in the [installation instructions](https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/). You need to *open* the zip file and copy the *contents* to your `htdocs` folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case 'wordpress' folder was inside another folder. I cut the 'wordpress' folder and pasted in inside 'htdocs'.

Answer (score 0):

please set virtual host on xampp (httpd-vhosts.conf)

like this

```
<VirtualHost localhost>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

note : check location htdocs in `C:` or `D:`

and then you can access it with `localhost/<file.php>`